# string replace for slashes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code for string replace but it doesn't work as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import fileinput
import string

filename = 'C:\sample\test\test.txt'
newfilename = string.replace(filename, '\\', '\\\\')
```

Expected output is `newfilename` should be `"C:\\\sample\\\test\\\test.txt"` but it is the same as `filename`.

What should I do to get the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this could look much simpler:

```
filename = r"C:\sample\test\test.txt"
newfilename = filename.replace('\\', '\\\\')

print newfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in your original filename string! Currently, you're setting `filename` to be `C\sample<tab>est<tab>est.txt`, where I've represented the tab character as .

Comment: The purpose of this code is to escape the backslashes !

Comment: You sadly cannot write code to escape backslashes once you have already put those backslashes into a string literal. You must either manually escape them, or use raw strings (as the accepted answer did).

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of `string.replace(filename, '\\', '\\\\')`, with `filename.replace('\\', '\\\\')`

Comment: And also you may have a problem with the '\t' and when you run the code is interpreting that as a TAB and not doing properly the replace, that's something to keep in mind